# iPad 2 website sizing issue

Tags: css, ipad, web, responsive-design, media-queries

Ok before I start I will begin by saying I am NOT an experienced web developer!

I am writing this website: http://leydencarcentre.co.uk

It looks reasonable on a desktop browser, but I am struggling with getting an iPad (2) to display it properly.

On an iPad in portrait orientation the "Home" page is zoomed in a bit when you open it, but you can't zoom out to get the whole page width on the screen.  The "MOT" page is zoomed out completely so the full width fits in.

In landscape on the iPad they both look correct.

My site is basically 960px fixed width, but note I have tried to make it a bit responsive using media queries. (It's NOT a fluid layout, but there are slightly different div widths for different sizes - Desktop, Tablet, Phone).  I've made the main background different colours for each type of layout so you can see when the CSS for each media type kicks in.  (the desktop one is white, the tablet antique white, and the mobile Orange).

Can anyone help with this?  I've googled things like "iPad website width" and I can't make sense of what's the best way to go.

Any help on this particular iPad issue or advice on my CSS and layout greatfully received!

I know fully responsive fluid layouts are the talk of the town but I'm looking to get this site done pretty quickly.  Do I *really* need a fully fluid layout?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: I forgot to mention I have tried playing around with the viewport tag...it's currently set to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: The reason it won't zoom out far enough in portrait is because the page isn't *long* enough to allow it to be zoomed out fully to fill the width.  The height gets fully zoomed out before the width can.

Comment: So should I just add some whitespace padding to the home page to make it longer?  Then I'd have surplus whitespace on the page when in landscape mode wouldn't I?

Comment: Is it a good solution?  Is fixing the viewport as suggested below worth a try?  I need guidance, I am not a web dude :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with cale_b in the end as I tried many viewport settings and it either displayed OK on the iPad but not on Chrome under android or vice versa.

So I added a minimum height to my main body div.

Thanks cale_b

Answer (score 4):

The easy fix:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000">
```

This will scale the iPad viewport to fit your page exactly (chrome told me body is 1000px wide).

In terms of mobile web good practices, I'd also add some scaling options so users can zoom in/out on different parts of the page.. something like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, minimum-scale=.5, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2.5">
```

Comment: Ah, the desktop CSS is 1000 wide, but notice that when you resize the browser narrower it switches the width to 960 (I did this to try and cater for the iPad in the first place...I read somewhere that 960 wide was a good width for the iPad).  So I need to FIX  the viewport to 960?  Is that a good thing to do in terms of interop across many devices?

Comment: Easy fix is set the site to 960px and set your viewport width=960. As long as you let users scale the site on mobile/tablet this will provide a decent user experience. If you go fully responsive, you're going to have to revisit your layout to make sure it works across all the different sized devices- for instance, repositioning side-content, persisting your navigation in an appropriate way per-device, and making sure everything stacks vertically in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Much harder to do responsive design as a retrofit :)

Comment: I tried the easy fix of setting the viewport to 960 with some min/max scale settings.  I couldn't try it on an iPad as I don't have connectivity until I get home, but I did try it on my Android phone.  It had a bizarre effect...the text in the menu and right bar was tiny but the paragraph text was large.  I've reverted back to the device-width setting now, mystery continues...